# How can I determine client_id from the identityserver3 login page URL

Tags: identityserver3

I have an MVC app that uses katana OpenIdConnectAuthentication to authenticate users with IdentityServer3 (v2.1.0).  The application supports two `client_id`s, which are used to differentiate between two sets of login page rules (one client_id uses local auth, the other uses external auth).

In OIDC's RedirectToIdentityProvider notification, I inspect the request URI, and if it contains a certain route, I set the client_id to the non-default value.

This works fine, but if a user bookmarks the login page URL, (e.g. https://localhost:44300/identity/login?signin=d35acc20864a8984001cfdc8e95bbf8d), they will not have the cookie matching the signin id, and will fall back to the `AuthenticationOptions.InvalidSignInRedirectUrl`, and there's no way to know which client_id they are trying to authenticate with.

I'd like to find a way to allow users to bookmark the login page URL and maintain the client_id information so that they end up on the right login page.

One thought I had was to setup a second instance of identity server, but I'd like to avoid that if there's a simpler solution.